# Split comma separated list ignoring commas within matching {}

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, split

I want to split a csv, but ignore any commas within matching curly brace groups, and loop through each of the list members.  The code below works great but does not consider commas within curly brace groups.

### Assumptions:

- There will *always* be matching pairs of curly braces.  That is, input such as  `{{ {a,b,c}, x` will *not* occur.

### Expected Output:

```
Word='{0,1}'
Word='alpha'
Word='{(x,y,z)}'
Word='{{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}'
```

### References:

- [How to split a list by comma not space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718307/how-to-split-a-list-by-comma-not-space)
- In case it matters I am on Mac OS 10.9.5.

### Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#TEST_STRING="alpha, beta, gamma" ## <--- works great for simple case
TEST_STRING="{0,1}, alpha, {(x,y,z)}, {{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}"

echo "${TEST_STRING}" | sed -n 1'p' | tr ',' '\n' | while read Extracted_Word; do
    printf "Word='%s'\n" "${Extracted_Word}"
done
```

---

I attemped to adapt 123's (now deleted) solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

#TEST_STRING="alpha, beta, gamma" ## <--- works great for simple case
TEST_STRING="{0,1}, alpha, {(x,y,z)}, {{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}"

echo "${TEST_STRING}" \
    | sed -n 1'p' \
    | sed 's/\({[^}]*\({[^}]*}[^}]*\)*} *\)\(,\|$\) */\1\n/g;:1;s/\(\n[^{}]*\), */\1\n/;t1' \
    | tr ',' '\n' \
    | while read Extracted_Word; do
    printf "Word='%s'\n" "${Extracted_Word}"
done
```

but this produces the following error message for me:

```
./testcsv.sh
sed: 1: "s/\({[^}]*\({[^}]*}[^}] ...": bad flag in substitute command: ':'
./testcsv.sh: line 18: {{ {a,b,c}, x: command not found
```

Comment: Judging by your test string: although you don't show expected output, it appears that you want to match nesting of braces.  That's beyond the capabilities of regular expressions, and so you need the capabilities of a context-free grammar; it's likely that sed is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Expected output shown.  I thought `sed` could do matching brace patterns? What would you suggest I use for this job?

Comment: _"I attemped to adapt 123's solution"_ - looks like you line-folded the sed script without adding `;` where the newlines were: `sed 's/\({[^}]*\({[^}]*}[^}]*\)*} *\)\(,\|$\) */\1\n/g;:1;s/\(\n[^{}]*\), */\1\n/;t1' `. (Actually, given that you're on MacOS, you might need newlines or separate `-e` expressions)  BTW, you could combine the two sed commands by adding `1q` to the end of the second one, to finish after the first line.  And drop the `tr`, since that's done within the sed command.

Comment: If you you have a fixed, small limit on the depth of nesting, you should be okay with regular expressions - and hence with sed.  For arbitrary nesting, you'll need something more, but I'm still thinking what that might be...

Comment: @TobySpeight: As I don't have the rep on this SE site to see the deleted answer, I tried copying your code in the comment (updated question to show that), but that did not produce the desired output (which was shown in the deleted answer).  Also, for my purposes, I am pretty sure I won't need a nesting depth more than what I have shown in the MWE.

Comment: @PeterGrill I have undeleted if you want to copy my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a pure **bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST_STRING="{0,1}, alpha, {(x,y,z)}, {{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}"
TEST_STRING="$TEST_STRING"","
count=0
newword=''
while [ "${TEST_STRING::1}" ] ; do 
    l="${TEST_STRING::1}"
    TEST_STRING=${TEST_STRING:1}
    [ "$l" = '{' ] && ((count++))
    [ "$l" = '}' ] && ((count--))
    if [ "$l" = ',' ] && ! ((count)) ; then
        echo "Word='$newword'"
        newword=''
    else
        if [ "$newword" ] || [ "$l" != " " ] ; then
            newword="$newword""$l"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: This breaks up the last one `{{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}`

Comment: @123 You are right! Have to think.

Comment: @123: Hey, what happened to your answer? I was trying to adapt it and an into difficulty. See updated question.

Comment: @Costas: Unforutantely, there isn't a character that I can guarantee that won't be in there. But, I do know that if there is a `#` character that it will _only_ appear as `\#`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Deleted it, it didn't work with more embedded brackets. Also you need to put `;` where the newlines were if you are putting the command on a single line.

Comment: @Costas: This indeed produces the desired output for the given example. However, I have two  minor issues: 1. If there is a `*` in the string being processed that gets replaced with the names of the files in the current directory. 2. I am not sure exactly where to place the call to the function which needs to process each member of the coma separated list as it appears that you build up the output string in several places. Is there a way to concatenate the string in memory and print each list entry in one place (then I can do my function call there.)

Comment: @PeterGrill 1. It is true if `*` is next to `,`. But if you expect this you can switch off globbing or add additional test into the code. 2. I'l update the code.

Comment: I think `$newworld` in the last `if` was meant to be `$newword`.  So, does that meant the the test cases did not execute all the various conditions?

Comment: @PeterGrill. Sure(have repaired). In the past condition just removes spaces(all). In the present - revoves spaces on the beginning only.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sed script that will split your example:

```
#!/bin/sed -Ef

# replace all commas with newlines
s/,/\
/g

# Do we need to re-join any lines?
:loop
# Unmatched brace containing possibly another (matched) level of
# braces:
s/(\{([^{}]|\{[^{}]*\})*)\
/\1,/
tloop

# remove any leading space
s/\n */\
/g

# At first line, print result, then exit.
1q
```

Caveat: it will only handle two levels of braces (as per the comments to the question).

#### Tests:

```
$ ./259252.sed <<<'{0,1}, alpha, {(x,y,z)}, {{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}'
{0,1}
alpha
{(x,y,z)}
{{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}
```

And to show that it exits after the first line is processed:

```
$ ./259252.sed <<<$'a,b,c\nd,e,f'
a
b
c
```

I'm running this on Linux, and using the answers to [Differences between sed on Mac OSX and other “standard” sed?](/q/13711/) to port it to MacOS.  If that doesn't work, then [this answer](//apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332) suggests you can install GNU sed with `brew install gnu-sed`, then use `gsed` instead of `sed` to invoke it.

#### In use:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

TEST_STRING="{0,1}, alpha, {(x,y,z)}, {{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}"

echo "${TEST_STRING}" | sed -E -f 259252.sed | while read Extracted_Word; do
    printf "Word='%s'\n" "${Extracted_Word}"
done
```

which gives:

```
Word='{0,1}'
Word='alpha'
Word='{(x,y,z)}'
Word='{{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}'
```

Comment: Nice answer ᠌ ᠌ ᠌

Comment: That looks promising, but can't figure out how to get it to work in my script so that I can loop through each of the entires. I also tried to run it as a standalone script and

Comment: @TobySpeight: The output I get is `Word='{0n1}n alphan {(xnynz)}n {{1n2n3}n {anbnc}}'`. I think the extra `n` in the output are the clue...

Comment: Does your sed not interpret `\n` as newline?  Check `sed -e 's/m/\n/g' <<<'...m...'` - you should get two rows of dots.

Comment: Not sure what the three `<<<` mean.  Three `<<<` gives me `Missing name for redirect.`. With `echo "...m..." | sed -e 's/m/\n/g'` I get a single line: `...n...`.

Comment: `<<<` is bash input from string - might be a Bash 4.x feature, and I hear Macs have 3.x.  Your test shows the problem; I've updated the answer with advice I found for installing GNU sed; I've reached my limit in getting what you want from your native sed, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

```
str='{0,1},alpha,{(x,y,z)},{{1,2,3},{a,b,c}}'
OPTIND=1 l=0 r=0; set ""
while   getopts : na -"$str"
do      [ "$l" -gt "$r" ]
        case    $?$OPTARG  in
        (1,)  ! l=0 r=0    ;;
        (0})    r=$((r+1)) ;;
        (?{)    l=$((l+1)) ;;
        esac    &&
        set -- "$@$OPTARG" ||
        set -- "$@" ""
done;   printf  %s\\n "$@"
```

`dash` has a bug which requires something like:

```
set -- "$@" ""; str=${str#?}
```

...but aside from that the above should be pretty quick as these things go, and work in basically any POSIX shell, besides being pretty simple all around. It should also handle mismatched pairs *(even if you don't need it)* by neglecting to specially recognize a `}` that occurs before a leading `{`.

---

```
{0,1}
alpha
{(x,y,z)}
{{1,2,3},{a,b,c}}
```

To get your prefixed string and the surrounding quotes you can substitute the following...

```
printf "Word='%s'\n" "$@"
```

...for the `printf %s\\n "$@"` used above. Given the example value of `$str` here it would print:

```
Word='{0,1}'
Word='alpha'
Word='{(x,y,z)}'
Word='{{1,2,3},{a,b,c}}'
```

More robustly you might do...

```
for W do alias "Word=$W" Word; done
```

...which would render...

```
Word='{0,1}'
Word=alpha
Word='{(x,y,z)}'
Word='{{1,2,3},{a,b,c}}'
```

...quoted as necessary, and would correctly quote embedded hard-quotes as well *(though, if using a `bash`, you might want to do `set --posix` first)*.

And so, for the sake of demonstration...

```
str="{0,1

}}, {,}alph}'a, {(x,y,z)}, {{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}" 
OPTIND=1 l=0 r=0; set ""
while   getopts : na -"$str"
do      [ "$l" -gt "$r" ]
        case    $?$OPTARG  in
        (1,)  ! l=0 r=0    ;;
        (0})    r=$((r+1)) ;;
        (?{)    l=$((l+1)) ;;
        esac    &&
        set -- "$@$OPTARG" ||
        set -- "$@" ""
done;   for W do alias "Word=${W# }" Word
done
```

---

```
Word='{0,1

}}'
Word='{,}alph}'\''a'
Word='{(x,y,z)}'
Word='{{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}'
```

...where even the leading spaces are handled quite simply...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on MacOS 10.9.5. I just get the original string `{0,1} alpha {(x,y,z)} {{1,2,3},{a,b,c}}` printed. To bad as I was hoping that this might actually ignore escaped curly braces, `\`{`, (not necessarily matching).

Comment: @PeterGrill - what is your shell? is it `bash` 2 or whatever Apple ships? I think it also ships `zsh`, where it does work for me. It also works in `bash` 4 at least, and `mksh` and `ksh93`. `bash` is just a bad shell, though it is marginally better these days than it was in the GPL 2 days. It uses POSIX syntax though, and so if it doesn't work on your system then it is because your system does not meet minimum unix standards.

Comment: @PeterGrill - but nowhere did I indicate that it would ignore *escaped* curly braces - though you could do that easily enough with a very little extra logic - at least to handle backslash escapes would be very simple and would require only one or two more `case` patterns in the test there.

Comment: Am on `3.2.53`. I guess I really should update to 4.x bash...

Answer (score 0):

An additional bash solution:

- It will handle unmatched pairs of braces `{`.
- Won't accept a closing brace until one or more opening braces appear.
- Will reset the count of braces to 0 at the end of the line.
- Will accept a comma as valid after more closing braces than opening braces.
- Will remove one space in front of solution.
- Will quote the resulting word.

Code:

```
str="}}{0,1}}, {,}alph}'a"

            fin='false' d='0'
until  $fin
do     IFS=   read -r -d '' -n 1 a || fin='true'
       if     [[ $a == '{' ]] ; then (( d++ )) ; fi ### count openning braces.
       if     [[ $a == ',' ]] && (( d<1 )) || $fin  ### ',' out of braces or end.
       then   $fin && s="${s%$'\n'}"                ### removing a last newline.
              set -- "$@" "$s"                      ### store in an array.
              unset a s d                           ### unset working variables.
       fi
       if [[ $a == '}' ]] && ((d>0)); then ((d--)); fi  ### close braces.
       s="$s$a"
done <<<"$str"
printf 'Word=%q\n' "${@# }"       ### print a quoted value removing front space.
```

---

Output:

```
Word=\}\}\{0\,1\}\}
Word=\{\,\}alph\}\'a
```

Or somewhat more cryptic:

```
str="{0,1

}}, {,}alph}'a, {(x,y,z)}, {{1,2,3}, {a,b,c}}"

        fin='false' d='0'
until  $fin
do     IFS=   read -r -d '' -n 1 a || fin='true'
       [[ $a == '{' ]] && (( d++ ))                 ### count openning braces.
       [[ $a == ',' ]] && (( d<1 )) || $fin && {    ### ',' no braces (or end).
              $fin && s="${s%$'\n'}"                ### removing a last newline.
              set -- "$@" "$s"                      ### store in an array.
              unset a s d                           ### unset working variables.
       }
       [[ $a == '}' ]] && (( d>0 )) && ((d--))      ### substract closing braces.
       s="$s$a"
done <<<"$str"
printf 'Word=%q\n' "${@# }"    ### print a quoted value with front space removed.
```

---

Result:

```
Word=$'{0,1\n\n}}'
Word=\{\,\}alph\}\'a
Word=\{\(x\,y\,z\)\}
Word=\{\{1\,2\,3\}\,\ \{a\,b\,c\}\}
```